# Apache not working after an Ubuntu server upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-12.04

I’ve just upgraded a server from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS given the imminent end of support for 10.04. The upgrade went fine; I have already tested it all with a virtual machine beforehand. However the webserver is no longer working.

When I run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It gives

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                        [ OK ]
```

So no error message, however the output from `ps ax` shows no evidence of apache actually running, likewise output from `netstat -tupln` doesn't show anything on port 80. I actually copied over the entire `/etc/apache2` folder from a different Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server that is working in case there was something up in one of the configuration files, but this didn’t fix it.

Does anyone know why it would not give an error message, but not actually be running?

I’ve checked the error log and there’s nothing added. Output from `/var/log/syslog` is

```
 Apr 28 16:28:37 ubuntu-server kernel: [ 9061.735298] apache2[13102]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fe46d8d7476 sp 00007ffd6f130ba8 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7fe46d7a6000+1b4000]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the system log in `/var/log/syslog` when you do an Apache2 restart. Meaning have one terminal window opened up with you viewing the `syslog` via [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) like this:

```
sudo tail -f -n 10 /var/log/syslog
```

And in the other window attempt to restart Apache. But your syntax of `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` seems clunky when you could just use [`service`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/service) like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I would also recommend manually stopping and starting it again by just doing these two commands in a row:

```
sudo service apache2 stop

sudo service apache2 start
```

Any deeper system issues with Apache should show up in the `syslog`. How to debug past that? Depends on what you see/read. But I’ve done tons of Ubuntu upgrades from earlier versions to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS without any issues.

**UPDATE:** Since the original poster has posted the output of `syslog`, might as well comment on it. It shows that there is some kind of segmentation fault happening when attempting to launch Apache:

```
Apr 28 16:28:37 ubuntu-server kernel: [ 9061.735298] apache2[13102]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fe46d8d7476 sp 00007ffd6f130ba8 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7fe46d7a6000+1b4000]
```

Segmentation faults like this can be a pain to track down. But in my experience a few major things could be causing this:

- **Bad/Corrupted PHP or HTML Code:** First, I doubt this is the case but am mentioning it anyway: I am assuming you are running PHP with Apache but this applies to HTML as well. The best way to check this is to set a simple `index.php` page and see what happens. But like I said, if Apache is borking on restart I doubt this is the case, but it is an idea.
- **Incompatible or Corrupted Apache2 Config or Setting:** You state that you are using a working Apache2 config from another, working Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server but there still might be a config issue you overlooked. For example, are the permissions on the `/etc/apache2` directory and it’s child directories correct? If you copied them over there is always the risk you might have overlooked ownership and permissions when setting that up so be sure to double-check that.
- **A Corrupted Apache2 Module:** It could be that a module connected to Apache is itself corrupted. If you have anything installed such as [APC (Alternative PHP Cache)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) I would recommend disabling it or even reinstalling it. To disable it, open up `/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini` and comment out the line that reads `extension=apc.so` with a `;` like this: `;extension=apc.so`.
- **Something Screwy in Apache2 Overall:** If all else fails, do a `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and then reinstall via a `sudo apt-get install apache2` and see what happens with a default install.

If all of that still does not kick the Apache2 process back to life, I would check other system services as well and see if they are even operational; they too could be showing segmentation faults in the `syslog`.

Also, you don’t state the depth or configuration of this system’s setup. But if it’s not elaborate at all—running only a few services where you are familiar with the config—it might be best to just discard this install and reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from scratch.

My personal server administration philosophy is to be very controlled and have backups of all configs and core files idiosyncratic to that server. That way if things get to be too much of a headache, I’ll just blow the problematic server away and start from scratch.